# Evaluating $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial {\bf{y}}}S\frac{\partial Z}{\partial {\bf{x}}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, quadratic-forms

Let ${\bf{x}}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a column vector:
$${\bf{x}} = \begin{pmatrix} x_{1} \\ \vdots \\ x_{n} \end{pmatrix} $$
and ${\bf{y}} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ analogously. Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n \times n$ matrices and consider the following objects:
$$Q({\bf{x}},{\bf{y}}) \equiv Q = {\bf{y}}^{T}A{\bf{x}} \quad \mbox{and} \quad Z({\bf{x}},{\bf{y}}) \equiv Z = ({\bf{y}}^{T}B{\bf{x}})^{2}$$
Moreover, let $S$ be a third $n \times n$ matrix. I want to calculate the following object:
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y_{i}}S_{ij}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x_{j}}$$

Applying the chain rule I found:
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y_{i}}S_{ij}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x_{j}} = ({\bf{y}}^{T}B{\bf{x}})({\bf{y}}^{T}A^{T}SB{\bf{x}})$$

Is my formula correct?

Comment: I have posted an answer below. Did it answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $Q=\sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij}y_ix_j$ and $Z=\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n B_{ij}y_ix_j\right)^2$. Hence we have $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y_i} = \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}x_k$$ and $$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x_j} =  2(\mathbf{y}^TB\mathbf{x})\sum_{l=1}^n B_{lj}y_j.$$
Thus $$\sum_{i,j=1}^n \frac{\partial Q}{\partial y_i}S_{ij}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x_j}=\sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^n 2(\mathbf{y}^TB\mathbf{x})A_{ik}x_kS_{ij}B_{lj}y_l =2(\mathbf{y}^TB\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{y}^TBS^TA\mathbf{x}).$$
Thus, the proposed formula $(\mathbf{y}^TB\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{y}^TA^TSB\mathbf{x})$ in the original post is *not* correct.

Note that both $\mathbf{y}^TB\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}^TBS^TA\mathbf{x}$ are scalars. Thus we have $\mathbf{y}^TB\mathbf{x} = (\mathbf{y}^TB\mathbf{x})^T = \mathbf{x}^TB^T\mathbf{y}$, and similarly we also have $\mathbf{y}^TBS^TA\mathbf{x}=(\mathbf{y}^TBS^TA\mathbf{x})^T=\mathbf{x}^TA^TSB^T\mathbf{y}$.